# Read and modify value stored in separate file using form and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I'm new to PHP so excuse me in advance! I have done the following code to show two different buttons depending on if $status in the file vars.php is set 1 or 0 using . So far so good.

The problem: I now trying to make a very simple page with two option fields to set the $status in the vars.php. I want the script to read what the value of $status is and pres-select the corresponding option box, and have a submit button that saved either 1 or 0 to $status.

It sounds so simple, but I can't get this it to work.. I don't want to use a database, the file can be txt, xml or whatever. Please anyone help me!

Below is the IF script that just checks for the status value 1 or else.

```
<?php include 'vars.php'; ?>
<?php if ($status == "1") { ?>
<a class="button" href="pageA.php">Read more</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a class="button" href="pageB.php">Read more</a>
<?php } ?>
```

What I'm trying to create is a tiny form with two options where I can swap the $status value between 1 and 0 (with the form option being pre-selected with whatever value $status has). When I press update it should overwrite the $status value in the vars.php.

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) & [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents).

Comment: Hi.. im not understanding exactly what you want. Can you provide what `vars.php` is?

Comment: Hi, In vars.php I only have the $status="1" where 1 is the value I want to be able to change with a form option between the values 1 and 0

Comment: I simply want to be able to change the $status value between 1 and 0 using a simple form with these 2 options. Hope I make any sense here lol! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JSON.

vars.json:

```
{
    "status": 1
}
```

then on your PHP:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("vars.json"));
$href = ($json->status) ? "pageA.php" : "pageB.php";
?>
<a class="button" href="<?= $href ?>">Read more</a>
```

UPDATE:  if you want to have a form set these variables without you having to manually modify the JSON data, then create another file, call it anything you want, we'll say form.php and place this inside:

```
 <?php
 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("vars.json"));
 if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
    $json->status = (int)$_POST['status'];
    file_put_contents('vars.json', json_encode($json));
 }
 ?>
 <form method="post">
     <label>Status</label>
     <select name="status">
        <option value="1" <?= ($json->status) ? "selected" : "" ?>>TRUE</option>
        <option value="0" <?= (!$json->status) ? "selected" : "" ?>>FALSE</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but is the actual changing of the value in the file using a form I'm trying to get working. The IF clause works great, but I want to avoid having to manually open the vars.php and change the value between 1 and 0. Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: hmm. so let me get this straight; you want a php file that has a form, this form will submit a 1 or 0 to the JSON file, which then can be read by another php file? Im a little confused, but definitely want to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Yes that is exactly what I trying to achieve. So whenever you change the value using the form, it should save/overwrite the value stored in the vars file!

Comment: ok, i placed an UPDATE on my answer showing you that. `form.php` will take care of updating the variables in vars.json.

Comment: I tried the from script, and it works great! But I'm not sure how to get the json code that shows the two diffrent links to work hmm. Also, instead of the value being in a input field, how can I change it do a option ? Thanks for taking your time !

Comment: Perfect, wow! The form works great now, But I think I must have missed something using the script on the page that swaps the links. Its shows pageB link regardless. Hmm! Soo close, thanks!

Comment: i doble checked it, it works fiine. Make sure, the form is saving the status as (int)

Comment: Ohh my bad, I forgot to add the folder path to the json file! It now works - your my hero for the day - thanks a lot!